# How can I filter a view according to another view's results

Tags: 7, views

I have one view with two display: "latest news" and "populer news"

I want show two block side by side like mashable.com.

I can easily do that of course but one problem. There are same news both block. 
I want to hide news in the "latest news block" according to "populer news block".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This module might help you [Views exclude previous](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous)

> The Views exclude previous module provides a views filter that
>   excludes nodes that have already been loaded/displayed on the current
>   page.

It excludes node in previous views loaded in your views. Example: you have two views block loading in the same page and the two block shows same node in views; you can exclude the other one in display, you can find the additional field in filter criteria in views configuration of your block. See image attached
[image: Excludes nodes that have already been loaded]